# XSLT | XPath can not find element with //

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

A have following XML:

```
<root>
 <request>
  <parameters>
     <DatabaseAlias>NSMFPROD</DatabaseAlias>
     <open-menu>yes</open-menu>
     <reports-section>_ALL</reports-section>
     <_path>/PrintHelper/ui/menu.xmsql:</_path>
     <P_BC_TYPE__desc>C</P_BC_TYPE__desc>
     <DocumentType>MISC.EXCEL.REG.CNTF.TYPES</DocumentType>
     <P_BC_TYPE>C</P_BC_TYPE>
     <P_NOM_ID/>
     <reports-repository>config/~reports/documents.xml</reports-repository>
     <P_DATE_FROM__desc>01.01.1900</P_DATE_FROM__desc>
     <p_run_document_type>MISC.EXCEL.REG.CNTF.TYPES</p_run_document_type>
     <P_CRN__desc>BGN</P_CRN__desc>
     <edit_reports-repository>default</edit_reports-repository>
     <P_DATE_FROM>01.01.1900</P_DATE_FROM>
     <sub-menu-name>run-reports</sub-menu-name>
     <P_NOM_ID__desc/>
     <out>debug.plain</out>
     <P_CRN>BGN</P_CRN>
     <P_DATE_TO>12.12.2016</P_DATE_TO>
     <menu-name>test</menu-name>
     <ReportRoot>
         http://localhost:8080/PrintHelper/config/~reports/documents.xml
     </ReportRoot>
     <P_DATE_TO__desc>12.12.2016</P_DATE_TO__desc>
   </parameters>
 </request>
 <data>
  <row row="1">
   <id>17912</id>
   <name>MBGA1S2аа</name>
   <emission>2002</emission>
   <bc_type>C</bc_type>
   <crn>BGN</crn>
   <denom_id>1 българска стотинка</denom_id>
   <wm_simulation/>
   <wm_position/>
   <sec_thread/>
   <imitation_mcrtext/>
   <foil_failure/>
   <iridescent_ovi/>
   <uv_paper_prop/>
   <fluor_fiber/>
   <pos_fiber/>
   <fluor_ink/>
   <ir_prop_ink/>
   <intaglio/>
   <min_lettering/>
   <sn_readability/>
   <register_purposely_reproduct>Не</register_purposely_reproduct>
   <prod_method/>
   <production_method_notes/>
   <reg_date>01.01.1900</reg_date>
   <first_usage_date/>
   <diameter>0</diameter>
   <weight>0</weight>
   <gurt_imitation>Не</gurt_imitation>
   <alloy/>
   <colour/>
   <magnetic_property/>
   <coins_sound/>
   <mint_mark/>
  </row>
 </data>
</root>
```

And this helper.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='windows-1251' ?>
<!-- $Id: ant.xml 5894 2011-04-05 07:57:57Z dtoshova $ -->
<root>
 <report code="EXCEL.MISC.POLICE" name="За органите на МВР">
   <ant>
     <report code="MISC.EXCEL.REG.CNTF.TYPES" name="Регистрирани типове">
    <ant>
        <column dataStyle="Text" dataType="Number" src="id" width="40" bc_type="BC" crn_code="BGN EUR USD">
            <text>ID</text>
        </column>
        <column dataStyle="Text" dataType="String" src="name" width="60" bc_type="BC" crn_code="BGN-EUR-USD">
            <text>Име</text>
        </column>
        <column dataStyle="Text" dataType="String" src="denom_id" width="60" bc_type="BC" crn_code="BGN-EUR-USD">
            <text>Номинал</text>
        </column>
        <column dataStyle="Text" dataType="String" src="emission" width="60" bc_type="BC" crn_code="BGN EUR USD">
            <text>Емисия</text>
        </column>
        <column dataStyle="Text" dataType="String" src="wm_simulation" width="100" bc_type="B" crn_code="BGN">
            <text>Имитация на полутоновия воден знак</text>
        </column>
        <column dataStyle="Text" dataType="String" src="wm_position" width="100" bc_type="B" crn_code="BGN">
            <text>Разположение на полутоновия воден знак</text>
        </column>
        <column dataStyle="Text" dataType="String" src="sec_thread" width="70" bc_type="B" crn_code="BGN">
            <text>Осигурителна нишка</text>
        </column>
        <column dataStyle="Text" dataType="String" src="imitation_mcrtext" width="70" bc_type="B" crn_code="BGN">
            <text>Имитация на микротекст в осигурителната нишка</text>
        </column>
        <column dataStyle="Text" dataType="String" src="foil_failure" width="70" bc_type="B" crn_code="BGN">
            <text>Холограмно фолио</text>
        </column>
        <column dataStyle="Text" dataType="String" src="iridescent_ovi" width="70" bc_type="B" crn_code="BGN">
            <text>OVI мастило</text>
        </column>
        <column dataStyle="Text" dataType="String" src="uv_paper_prop" width="70" bc_type="B" crn_code="BGN">
            <text>UV свойства на хартията</text>
        </column>
        <column dataStyle="Text" dataType="String" src="fluor_fiber" width="70" bc_type="B" crn_code="BGN">
            <text>Флуоресциращи влакънца</text>
        </column>
        <column dataStyle="Text" dataType="String" src="pos_fiber" width="70" bc_type="B" crn_code="BGN">
            <text>Разположение на флуоресциращите влакънца</text>
        </column>
        <column dataStyle="Text" dataType="String" src="fluor_ink" width="70" bc_type="B" crn_code="BGN">
            <text>Флуоресциращи мастила</text>
        </column>
        <column dataStyle="Text" dataType="String" src="ir_prop_ink" width="70" bc_type="B" crn_code="BGN">
            <text>IR (инфрачервени) свойства на мастилата</text>
        </column>
        <column dataStyle="Text" dataType="String" src="intaglio" width="70" bc_type="B" crn_code="BGN">
            <text>Релефен печат</text>
        </column>
        <column dataStyle="Text" dataType="String" src="min_lettering" width="70" bc_type="B" crn_code="BGN">
            <text>Микро- или мини текст</text>
        </column>
        <column dataStyle="Text" dataType="String" src="sn_readability" width="70" bc_type="B" crn_code="BGN">
            <text>Сериен номер - четимост</text>
        </column>
        <column dataStyle="Text" dataType="String" src="register_purposely_reproduct" width="70" bc_type="B" crn_code="BGN">
            <text>Преднамерено възпроизведен регистър на проглед</text>
        </column>
        <column dataStyle="Text" dataType="String" src="diameter" width="70" bc_type="C" crn_code="BGN">
            <text>Диаметър</text>
        </column>
        <column dataStyle="Text" dataType="String" src="weight" width="70" bc_type="C" crn_code="BGN">
            <text>Тегло</text>
        </column>
        <column dataStyle="Text" dataType="String" src="gurt_imitation" width="70" bc_type="C" crn_code="BGN">
            <text>Имитация на гурт</text>
        </column>
        <column dataStyle="Text" dataType="String" src="alloy" width="70" bc_type="C" crn_code="BGN">
            <text>Сплав</text>
        </column>
        <column dataStyle="Text" dataType="String" src="colour" width="70" bc_type="C" crn_code="BGN">
            <text>Цвят</text>
        </column>
        <column dataStyle="Text" dataType="String" src="magnetic_property" width="70" bc_type="C" crn_code="BGN">
            <text>Магнитни свойства</text>
        </column>
        <column dataStyle="Text" dataType="String" src="coins_sound" width="70" bc_type="C" crn_code="BGN">
            <text>Звук</text>
        </column>
        <column dataStyle="Text" dataType="String" src="mint_mark" width="70" bc_type="C" crn_code="EUR">
            <text>Mint mark</text>
        </column>
        <column dataStyle="Text" dataType="String" src="prod_method" width="70" bc_type="BC" crn_code="BGN-EUR-USD">
            <text>Начин на производство</text>
        </column>
        <column dataStyle="Text" dataType="String" src="production_method_notes" width="100" bc_type="BC" crn_code="BGN-EUR-USD">
            <text>Бележки - начин на производство</text>
        </column>
        <column dataStyle="Text" dataType="String" src="reg_date" width="30" bc_type="BC" crn_code="BGN-EUR-USD">
            <text>Дата на създаване</text>
        </column>
        <column dataStyle="Text" dataType="String" src="first_usage_date" width="30" bc_type="BC" crn_code="BGN">
            <text>Дата на първо регистриране</text>
        </column>
    </ant>
    <params>
        <param code="P_BC_TYPE" name="вид"/>
        <param code="P_CRN" name="валута"/>
        <param code="P_NOM_ID" name="номинал"/>
        <param code="P_DATE_FROM" name="от дата"/>
        <param code="P_DATE_TO" name="до дата"/>
    </params>
  </report>
</root>
```

I have this xsl transformation:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
    xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
    xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
    xmlns:debug="urn:local:debug"
    xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common">

<xsl:import href="../excel-styles.xsl"/>
<xsl:import href="../excel-common.xsl"/>

<!--select="document('../../documents.xml')/documents/section/type[@code = $local.document.type]"/-->
<xsl:param name="local.document" select="//request/parameters/DocumentType"/>
<xsl:param name="local.helper" select="document('helper.xml')/root/report[@code = $local.document]"/>
<xsl:param name="local.params.values" select="document('params.xml')/root"/>
<xsl:param name="local.params" select="//request/parameters"/>
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="windows-1251"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:processing-instruction name="mso-application">
        <xsl:text>progid="Excel.Sheet"</xsl:text>
    </xsl:processing-instruction>
    <Workbook>
        <xsl:call-template name="excel.xsl-processor-info"/>
        <DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
            <Author>
                <xsl:text>$Id: $</xsl:text>
            </Author>
            <Created/>
        </DocumentProperties>
        <Styles>
            <xsl:call-template name="excel.styles.static"/>
        </Styles>
        <Worksheet ss:Name="report">
            <Table>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$local.helper/params/param" mode="param_row">
                    <xsl:with-param name="paramset" select="//parameters"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="dataparamset" select="//data_parameters"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </Table>
            <xsl:call-template name="types_sheet"/>
        </Worksheet>
    </Workbook>             
</xsl:template>

<!--Отделните таблици на типовете-->
<xsl:template name="types_sheet">
    <Table>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="cellBold">
            <ss:Data ss:Type="String">
                <xsl:value-of select="//P_BC_TYPE"/>
            </ss:Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="cellBold">
            <ss:Data ss:Type="String">
                <xsl:value-of select="//P_CRN"/>
            </ss:Data>
        </Cell>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$local.helper/ant/column[contains (@bc_type,//P_BC_TYPE)][contains (@crn_code,//P_CRN)]" mode="dd"/>

        <!--широчината на колоните-->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$local.helper/ant/column[contains (@bc_type,//P_BC_TYPE)][contains (@crn_code,//P_CRN)]" mode="columns_width">
            <xsl:with-param name="columns" select="$local.params"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
        <!--антетката-->
        <Row>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$local.helper/ant/column[contains (@bc_type,//P_BC_TYPE)][contains (@crn_code,//P_CRN)]" mode="ant_cells">
                <xsl:with-param name="columns" select="$local.params"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </Row>
        <!--данните-->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//data/row[crn=//P_CRN][bc_type=//P_BC_TYPE]" mode="data_rows">
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </Table>        
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="column" mode="dd">
    <Row>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="cellBold">
        <ss:Data ss:Type="String">
            <xsl:value-of select="column/text"/>
        </ss:Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="cellBold">
        <ss:Data ss:Type="String">
            <xsl:value-of select="@bc_type"/>
        </ss:Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="cellBold">
        <ss:Data ss:Type="String">
            <xsl:value-of select="@crn_code"/>
        </ss:Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="cellBold">
        <ss:Data ss:Type="String">
            <xsl:value-of select="//P_BC_TYPE"/>
        </ss:Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="cellBold">
        <ss:Data ss:Type="String">
            <xsl:value-of select="//P_CRN"/>
        </ss:Data>
    </Cell>
    </Row>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The problem is that when i select first time **//P_BC_TYPE** and **//P_CRN** in

> xsl:template match="/">

it return **C** and **BGN**, but when select them in

> xsl:template match="column" mode="dd">

it return to me empty string(even when I select them with **/root/request/parameters/P_BC_TYPE**). Why XPath can not find them?

Comment: tldr; - is the column template applied to a node in the same document than the xpath you are looking for, or applied to a node in your helper xml? If the latter, then the xpath will try to find a match inside the helper

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there any option to access them in <xsl:template match="column" mode="dd">?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work because the context node of that template is in the other xml document, so the xpath will be evaluated against that. The solution is not so difficult:

create a new variable (below your params)

```
<xsl:variable name="origdoc" select="/"/>
```

and where you need the xpath, use it with the $origdoc e.g.: (no need for `//`, it will start at the top of $origdoc anyway)

```
<xsl:value-of select="$origdoc/P_BC_TYPE"/>
```